# How to loop through Python DataFrame GroupBy Object and change values in the DataFrame based on calculations between rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Python DataFrame sales_production_stock:

| date | model_year | model_year | production | sales prediction | Modified Stock | Starting Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-01 | model1 | 2019 | 5 | 19 | 568 | 568 |
| 2020-05-01 | model1 | 2020 | 6 | 7386 | 10063 | 10063 |
| 2020-06-01 | model1 | 2019 | 0 | 965 | -397 |  |
| 2020-06-01 | model1 | 2020 | 8 | 6106 | 3965 |  |

I am attempting to iterate over the DataFrame to generate a "sell-down" where modified stock goes to 0 for older model years as production ends and remaining stock gets sold off based on the following criteria:

**Modified Stock first value** = Starting Stock first value for each model year

**Modified Stock subsequent values** = Current Production + Previous Month Modified Stock - current Sales prediction for each model year

For example for the 2019 in 2020-06-01 this would be Production (0) + Previous Starting Stock value (568) - predicted sales (965). This gives us -397.

When this number is negative that means there are too many predicted sales/not enough production/ not enough stock to come back with a positive ending stock. In this situation I would like to make the 2019 predicted sales = previous month 2020-05-01 ending stock (568) + any production in 2020-06-01 (0)

Then I'd like to increase the sales prediction of the next model year (2020) in 2020-06-01 by the difference of 397 which would change the original 2020 sales prediction (6106) + (397) and change the new Modified Stock for the 2020 in 2020-06-01 to 3568 which would result in a DataFrame like this:

| date | model | model_year | production | sales prediction | Modified Stock | Starting Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-01 | model1 | 2019 | 5 | 19 | 568 | 568 |
| 2020-05-01 | model1 | 2020 | 6 | 7386 | 10063 | 10063 |
| 2020-06-01 | model1 | 2019 | 0 | **568** | **0** |  |
| 2020-06-01 | model1 | 2020 | 8 | **6503** | **3568** |  |

What I came up with is the following:

```
dfs = []

for name, df in sales_production_stock.groupby(['model', 'model_year']):
    df.loc[df.index[0], 'Modified_Stock'] = df.loc[df.index[0], 'Starting_Stock']
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        
            
        if df.loc[df.index[i], 'predicted_sales'] > df.loc[df.index[i-1], 'Modified_Stock'] + df.loc[df.index[i], 'production']:
            
            diff = df.loc[df.index[i], 'predicted_sales'] - df.loc[df.index[i-1], 'Modified_Stock'] + df.loc[df.index[i], 'production']
            df.loc[df.index[i], 'predicted_sales'] = df.loc[df.index[i-1], 'Modified_Stock'] + df.loc[df.index[i], 'production']
            
            sales_production_stock.loc[sales_production_stock.model_year == df.loc[df.index[i], 'model_year'] + 1, 'predicted_sales'] = sales_production_stock.loc[sales_production_stock.model_year == df.loc[df.index[i], 'model_year'] + 1, 'predicted_sales'] + diff
        
        df.loc[df.index[i], 'Modified_Stock'] = df.loc[df.index[i-1], 'Modified_Stock'] + df.loc[df.index[i], 'production'] - df.loc[df.index[i], 'predicted_sales']
    dfs.append(df)
```

It does everything but assign the difference to the next model year in this block of code:

```
sales_production_stock.loc[sales_production_stock.model_year == df.loc[df.index[i], 'model_year'] + 1, 'predicted_sales'] = sales_production_stock.loc[sales_production_stock.model_year == df.loc[df.index[i], 'model_year'] + 1, 'predicted_sales'] + diff
```

I originally tried .apply() with similar code but figured it needed to loop through the model_years 1 by 1 instead of in parallel.

I am hoping someone can either suggest a better way all together or let me know how to apply the diff to the next model year within this context and still calculate the modified ending stock with the adjusted sales predictions.

The example data is just for one model but I need to apply this to a DataFrame with many models and model years

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: You're example data is incomplete as it doesn't include 'model'. Makes it difficult to validate what you've done so far. Also, adding what you are expecting as output dataframe would be helpful. the second table provided is not complete, correct?

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my post @JonathanLeon. I added model to the tables. The example data is just for one model but I need to apply this to a DataFrame with many models and model years. I also bolded the changes I hope to see in the output dataframe but the second table is the complete change I would like to end up with